# Reading arguments from a text file using <

Tags: c++, shell, unix

I have a txt file called test.txt that looks like this,

```
hi this is a test
```

and I have a c++ file called selection_sort.cpp that looks like this,

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    cout << argc << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        cout << argv[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

right now when I compile my program in my terminal with

```
g++ selection_sort.cpp -o selection_sort
```

and then try and print out all of of the arguments I am trying to pass using my code like this

```
./selection_sort < test.txt
```

but it only outputs

```
./selecton_sort
```

I would like it to output

```
./selection_sort
hi
this
is
a
test
```

What am I missing or doing wrong? I need to use the <.

Comment: `./selection_sort < test.txt` passes no arguments (except for the program name itself). So you can't get the text from `argv`; you need to use `std::cin >> word` instead (or some of the equivalent methods/functions).

Comment: The shell operator `< test.txt` send the content of the file 'test.txt' to the standard input of the application. You can read this data from `std::cin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I missing or doing wrong? I need to use the <.

This is a shell operator that sends the content of the file to the standard input of the application.

```
./app < text.file
```

Will read the file `text.file` and send the conent to the standard input of the application `app`. In C++ you can read the standard input via `std::cin`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{    
    std::string word;
    while (std::cin >> word) {
        std::cout << word << "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`<` in bash is used to redirect input. In other words, it redirects the standard input for your process to the file. However, command line arguments (e.g. `argv` arguments) are *not* read through standard input, so you cannot capture them from a file by redirecting input.

Rather, they are provided as arguments when running the command in bash to begin with. You can accomplish your goal like so:

```
./selection_sort $(cat test.txt)
```

`cat` is for concatenating files, but if you supply it just one file, it will just output the contents of the file through standard out. The `$(x)` operation will execute the `x` command in a subshell, capture its standard output (which in this case is the contents of the file), and then do variable substitution to replace `$(x)` with said contents.

**Edit:**

Or, you can just change the way the arguments are accepted, so that they *are* accepted via standard input. It depends on how you want to be able to run the program.